# How do we think of a field in the context of group theory?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, vector-fields

The definition of a field (in the context of group theory) that I've been taught is as follows:

"A field is defined as being a set $F$, combined with the binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$"

This (to me) implies that a field is a group given by $\{ F, * \}$, where $*$ denotes the 2 operations $+$ and $\cdot$

However, to be a group, it would have to have an identity element, but there cannot exist some $x \in F$ such that $f+x = f$ and $f \cdot x = e$. This would imply that I am incorrect in thinking that a field is like a group.

Comment: The multiplicative operation makes $F$ a group only if you remove the zero element.  So a field does have two groups involved, $\langle F,+\rangle$ and $\langle F*,\times\rangle$, where $F^*$ is $F$ with the zero element removed.

Comment: It's not very precise to say $\{F,*\}$ is a group where $*$ denotes two operations.  A group has one operation.

Answer (score 3):

A group is a set equiped with just one operator that satisfies some axioms. A field is something else entirely since it has two operators. However if $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field then $(F,+)$ is always an abelian group and so is $(F\setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$. These groups are typically called the additive group of the field and the multiplicative group of the field respectively.

Comment: Nice answer. I suggest adding paragraph pointing out that the two operations are _connected_ by the axiom that says multiplication distributes over addition. It's the only field axiom that mentions both operations.(You might consider $0 \ne 1$ another.)

Answer (score 1):

Attached to a field $F$ are two groups, namely the additive group $(F,+)$ and the multiplicative $(F^{\times},\cdot)$. Every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is *cyclic*, i.e., of a particular easy structure. Furthermore, if we have a field extension $E\supset F$, which is Galois, then we obtain another interesting group, namely the *Galois group*
$Gal(E/K)$. So there are certainly many relations between fields and groups. However, groups and fields are quite different things themselves, of course.